# AutoHotkey to use clipboard info to open files in Word works in Win8 but not in Win7

Tags: macros, autohotkey

I created an AHK macro for a colleague. I have Windows 8; she has Windows 7. She has two "pending work" folders, one for documents and the other for audio files. The (text) file names in the documents folder correspond to the file names in the audio folder. So, for example, if there is an audio file called `abc123.mp3` in the audio folder, there will be a file named `abc123.txt` in the documents folder.

As she opens the audio file in her transcription (media player) app, as part of that process, I want to have an AHK macro automatically open the matching text file (in Word).

I created an AHK macro that picks up from the point of her selecting the file to open from her transcription app. At the point where she selects the file, she invokes the AHK shortcut, which then toggles the rename feature (<kbd>F2</kbd>), copies the text to the clipboard (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>), opens the file (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>), and then uses the clipboard info (along with path info) to open the appropriate text file in Word.

It's working PERFECTLY on my system. However, when I logged into her system earlier today to demo the macros, the macro would not work. It works to a point - it will rename the file, copy the name of the file, and open the audio file, and file name is in the clipboard. But that's where it dies, with no error message. During troubleshooting, I tried isolating the macro down to one command - to simply open (fixed name) file in `WinWord.exe`, but that doesn't work, either.

I have been unable to find any research related to this issue. I know there are numerous ways to accomplish this task, but my AHK scripting skills and my free time are limited, so I went with what I knew I could accomplish quickly. I am open to suggestions for how to troubleshoot or tweak this macro to get it working on her system. It's hard to troubleshoot when it works on mine!

```
NumpadEnter::
Send {F2}{Sleep 100}
Clipboard=
Send ^c
Send {Sleep 100}!o{Sleep 100}
Run, WinWord.exe "C:\DocFiles\"%Clipboard%.txt
Return
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a guess, but I believe you wanted Sleep command and not a Sleep Key? Be sure that you are using the Latest Version of AutoHotkey you can download it from [www.ahkscript.org](http://www.ahkscript.org)

```
NumpadEnter::
Send {F2}
Sleep, 100
Clipboard=
Send, ^c
Run, WinWord.exe "C:\DocFiles\"%Clipboard%.txt
Sleep 100
Send, ^o
Sleep 100
Send, ^v
Sleep 100
Send, !o
Return
```

Edit:

In the script you posted, you are telling the computer to [Send](http://ahkscript.org/docs/commands/Send.htm) a [Sleep Key](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CB8QFjAAahUKEwiPj5jIpvfGAhXCM4gKHYcbCEc&url=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FPower_management_keys&ei=swm0Vc_pGcLnoASHt6C4BA&usg=AFQjCNGBETuZZHbJZCImm9RCsCXeqZkP5w&sig2=xCygfb1OsLiKq8yHoAqqPA&bvm=bv.98717601,d.cGU&cad=rja) by placing brackets around the word Sleep. Like so `{Sleep}`

Furthermore, you are also telling your script to not just [Send](http://ahkscript.org/docs/commands/Send.htm) one key... you are telling it to [Send](http://ahkscript.org/docs/commands/Send.htm) the [Sleep Key](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CB8QFjAAahUKEwiPj5jIpvfGAhXCM4gKHYcbCEc&url=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FPower_management_keys&ei=swm0Vc_pGcLnoASHt6C4BA&usg=AFQjCNGBETuZZHbJZCImm9RCsCXeqZkP5w&sig2=xCygfb1OsLiKq8yHoAqqPA&bvm=bv.98717601,d.cGU&cad=rja) [100 times by placing the number 100 in the brackets, separated by a space, with the named key.](http://ahkscript.org/docs/commands/Send.htm#Repeating__or_Holding_Down_a_Key) Like so: `{Sleep 100}`

I fail to see how you would want to have your script simulate 100 Sleep key presses?

What I posted above uses the [Sleep Command](http://ahkscript.org/docs/commands/Sleep.htm) which delays the script in milliseconds. I believe this is truly what you want.

Comment: Hi, ahkcoder - The way you see my script is how I've always set up my scripts, with Sleep and the time span) in brackets, and no commas after "Send." I know just enough about AHK to be dangerous! It is working just fine on my end, though, so nothing to clue me in that I was invoking the Sleep key. 

I will redo my script to match what you have done and send her the updated script file. I haven't updated my copy of AHK in a while (but I will now), but she just downloaded hers  yesterday, so I am sure she has the latest version. I'll post back soon with an update. Thanks!

Comment: P.S. As I was looking more closely at your script and my original script, I realized I had posted a wrong (much earlier) version of my script. The paste and open commands went with a very early iteration of the script. I have edited my original post to reflect the latest version, and I've also tweaked your suggested script to eliminated the unnecessary commands. Sorry about the confusion!

Comment: Be aware that if either you or your co-worker downloaded AutoHotkey from www.autohotkey.com you are using an Old unsupported version. The newest latest version is at www.ahkscript.org (google still directs people to the Old website). No worries I edited with additional links that explain further what was wrong with the original script. Can you please mark this question answered?

Comment: Yes, I understood what you were saying when you mentioned the Sleep Command. I have changed my script to be formatted the way you have shown (including Sleep with no brackets, and "Send," instructions on each new line of code. I am tentatively scheduled to get together with my colleague tomorrow (Sunday) to test out the new macro, so I'll post back after that as to whether it's working or not. I didn't mark the question answered because I thought I was supposed to wait until it's resolved. Still a newb and not sure how these things work. But I'll mark it answered, since you asked. :) Thanks!

Comment: @ahkcoder just fyi the version available for download on www.autohotkey.com is the same version as you can download from www.ahkscript.org for a few months now. The online documentation on the www.autohotkey.com site is outdated and one should refer to the installed help file or the online documentation at www.ahkscript.org